# Facebook Login 4.x | IOS 9 | Swift 2 | Safari View Controller Cookies

Tags: swift, cookies, ios9, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

i have a problem with new Facebook IOS SDK.

Using SafariViewController with new Facebook SDK is OK for me but it doesn't remember email and password after first login.

In Safari my Facebook account already logged in and here is my code:

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web

    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Is it because you're calling `logOut()`?

Comment: I don't think so. logOut() is about keeping user authentication at server side and i already tried without fbLoginManager.logOut() line. Same result.